# Query to update date only without timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

I have millions of records which have date as 06-OCT-20 with some timestamp  for which I want to update to 30-SEP-20 with the same timestamp
Timestamp should remain same  but need to change the date only .

Example as below

"06-OCT-20 06.30.04" to "30-SEP-20 06.30.04" ,
"06-OCT-20 05.29.04" to "30-SEP-20 05.29.04" ,
"06-OCT-20 00.28.04" to "30-SEP-20 00.28.04" ,
"06-OCT-20 09.45.04" to "30-SEP-20 09.45.04" ,
"06-OCT-20 07.30.04" to "30-SEP-20 07.30.04" ,

in Oracle.

Comment: All of the rows currently have the same date part, 2020-10-06, and all have to change to the same date part, 2020-09-30? i.e. you just want to subtract 7 days from every value? More sample data with expected results might be helpful.

Comment: 06-OCT-20 08.30.21 want to update as 30-SEP-20 08.30.21

timestamp shouldnot change ,only the date needs to be updated looking for oracle update query

Comment: That's what I've assumed in my answer; but please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64247519/edit) to give examples, and clarify the description of the problem - as you can see from Gordon's answer, it isn't clear at the moment. It *says* that you have millions of rows with exactly the same date and time, whereas you actually seem to have millions of rows on the same date but with different times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to modify values which are on October 6th, and make them have the same time but on September 30th, then you can subtract 6 days from them:

```
update your_table
set some_date = some_date - interval '6' day
where some_date >= date '2020-10-06'
and some_date < date '2020-10-07';
```

The filter restricts the update to values on that day.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9a93c384c7263579e2944e44ac4232aa)

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
update t
    set date = timestamp '2020-09-30 06:30:04'
    where date = timestamp '2020-10-06 06:30:04';
```

Comment: this is simple timestamp is not same throughout

Comment: @Siphali . . . This answers exactly the question that you have asked.